# Collision dectection acting randomly

Tags: swift, collision-detection

I have recently started making a game. My collision detection seems to be faulty as 90% of the time my score is increasing by 1, but it will randomly go up by 2 which I want to fix. The game is basically a parody of Flappy Bird that collects coins in between each wall. My quesion is, has anyone had this problem in the past? Where the score is inconsistantly increasing? I am using an animation of a bird to collect the coins. The game also lags a tiny bit before collecting each coin. Thanks in advance, any info is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the player or coin mesh is not manifold - i.e. it's being detected twice occasionally because the rigid-body property has automatically built two collision domains that overlap (not ideal on a single entity).

Maybe try to use a different type of convex hull? Or maybe you need to refine your model. Either way, I would recommend looking into the possibility that collisions are being detected twice on either of the involved entities. IF that's not the case, I would suggest that your code might be buggy - you could lock your score increment (per coin) after a single collision, so that multiple registers do not occur for the one coin.

P.S. Sorry if I'm way off base with my answer - your question is a bit lacking in detail :)

Comment: Well my bird is quite a complex shape,  so i set the Physics Body shape to a texture. The coin is just a simple rectangleOfSize. I am not at home so dont have the code on me but I can upload it in a few hours!

Comment: I have added another more detailed question for this. If you could have a look that would be great! No-one else is helping :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116566/collision-detection-causing-score-to-be-random